# Using RedirecResponse outside Laravel

Tags: php, session, laravel

I'm connecting my external App to do some actions into Laravel 5, get the response and continue. One of this actions is a login usign Laravel code:

## Outside Laravel

```php
<?php
use Laravel\Laravel;

# Some code here but not headers or html output
Laravel::login();

# Another some code more and then print login form from laravel blade template
echo Laravel::loginView();
```

## Laravel custom connection class (outside Laravel)

```php
<?php
namespace Laravel;

use App;
use Illuminate;

class Laravel
{
    private static $app;

    private static function load()
    {
        require_once self::getPath('bootstrap/autoload.php');

        self::$app = require_once self::getPath('bootstrap/app.php');

        self::$app->make('Illuminate\\Contracts\\Http\\Kernel')->handle(Illuminate\Http\Request::capture());
    }

    public static function login()
    {
        self::load();

        $response = App::make('App\\Http\\Controllers\\User')->login($_POST);

        if ($response instanceof RedirectResponse) {
            # Here I want to stop my app, save cookies/headers from Laravel Login
            # and redirect to $response target url location
            # If I do it with a simple Location redirect, I lost cookies and headers
            # and User will be not authenticated on next request
            die($response);
        }
    }

    public static function loginView()
    {
        self::load();

        return view('pages.users.login');
    }
}
```

## Laravel App\Http\Controllers\User@login

```php
class User
{
    public function login($data)
    {
        $success = Auth::attempt([
            'user' => $data['user'],
            'password' => $data['password'],
        ], $data['remember']);

        if ($success) {
            return redirect()->to(url('/'));
        }
    }
}
```

I have all code working (view templates, user validation, login) but I need at end redirect the login response with headers and cookies to be available on next request.

There are a simple and clean way to do it? (There are more code, but it simplified here)

Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple and clean way to do this, I came here looking to do the same thing and [this page](http://www.gufran.me/post/laravel-illuminate-router-package-in-your-application/) showed me that simply adding a call to `->send()` on a response *will send the response*.  In your case, the `login` method could look like this:

```
public function login($data)
{
    $success = Auth::attempt([
        'user' => $data['user'],
        'password' => $data['password'],
    ], $data['remember']);

    if ($success) {
        $response = redirect()->to(url('/'));
        $response->send();
        return $response;
    }
}
```

If there is a single spot in your integration where you are calling your controller methods, it would make more sense to place the call there so that you don't actually call `->send()` from within your controller (as Laravel doesn't).